# Unable to access Jenkins on compute engine on google cloud

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I've installed Jenkins on my Ubuntu machine running on compute engine in Google Cloud with below commands.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql git openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk -y
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Jenkins seems to be installing fine but when i go to the public IP address on port 8080 nothing is opening and I'm getting timeout error.

I found similar question [Jenkins not showing on Ubuntu through google cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584404/jenkins-not-showing-on-ubuntu-through-google-cloud/44609837#44609837?newreg=dbb4f4e8ae1c47e28d1acf09781fd630) but I have done the firewall rules part mentioned here but still I am not able to open the address on port 8080.

1.Name for the rule - jenkins-rule.
2.Direction is ingress
3.Action on match is Allow
4.Targets is All instances
5.Source IP ranges is 0.0.0.0/0
6.Protocols and ports is tcp:8080

Comment: Looks like you have installed jenkins but not started it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already configured FW rules, it's seem to me you need to restart the Jenkins service

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```

If not work reset the VM and check it after cheeking the status of the Jenkins service

```
sudo systemctl status jenkins
```

For me it works!

Comment: I did what you asked but still not able to connect. I'm getting error "internal error - server connection terminated
Description: internal error - server connection terminated"

Comment: What is the output of "sudo systemctl status jenkins"

Comment: I followed this docs https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: the output of status command is "● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2021-01-14 14:18:28 UTC; 37min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1891 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/jenkins stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1939 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
" and I followed the same steps mentioned in digitalocean page but to no luck. Thanks for your response.

Comment: can you use 'nmap -Pn IP-Address' to check that port 8080 is open or not

Comment: yes it seems port is open. this is the output of the command "Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-01-15 13:28 UTC
Nmap scan report for 62.121.197.104.bc.googleusercontent.com (104.197.121.62)
Host is up (0.0015s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
8080/tcp open  http-proxy"

Comment: I finally got to the unlock screen. The culprit is VPN. This is my company PC and I was doing this activity with VPN connected :( I should've been wiser. Thanks for your help though :)